# Swift 3 - Mapkkt, given a set route add a pin X km along it

Tags: swift, mapkit

You can see from the code that I have an array of locations and I create a route from one to the next. I want to be able to plot X km along it. I'm not sure how to do this. I know I'll need to get coordinates but don't know how to do the starting point + X km along a set route.

```
// Create Map
        mapView.delegate = self

        // Create locations array
        let locations = [
            ["title": "St. John's, NL",    "latitude": 47.561510, "longitude": -52.712577],
            ["title": "Gander, NL", "latitude": 48.954408, "longitude": -54.610349],
            ["title": "Port-Aux-Basques, NL",     "latitude": 47.572115, "longitude": -59.136429],
            ["title": "Sheet Harbour, NS",     "latitude": 44.927851, "longitude": -62.544239],
            ["title": "Darmouth, NS",     "latitude": 44.665206, "longitude": -63.567743],
            ["title": "Charlottetown, PE",     "latitude": 46.238240, "longitude": -63.13107],
            ["title": "Saint John, NB",     "latitude": 45.273315, "longitude": -66.063308],
            ["title": "Bristol, New Brunswick",     "latitude": 46.471094, "longitude": -67.580683],
            ["title": "HWY 185, QC",     "latitude": 47.665387, "longitude": -69.169922],
            ["title": "Quebec City, QC",     "latitude": 46.769968, "longitude": -71.279297],
            ["title": "Montréal, QC",     "latitude": 45.490946, "longitude": -73.586426],
            ["title": "Ottawa, ON",     "latitude": 45.420624, "longitude": -75.691681],
            ["title": "Hawksbury, ON",     "latitude": 45.607793, "longitude": -74.614162],
            ["title": "Pickering, ON",     "latitude": 43.837994, "longitude": -79.082336],
            ["title": "Toronto, ON",     "latitude": 43.649988, "longitude": -79.385834],
            ["title": "Hamilton, ON",     "latitude": 43.260206, "longitude": -79.888458],
            ["title": "London, ON",     "latitude": 42.98707, "longitude": -81.245956],
            ["title": "Gravenhurst, ON",     "latitude": 44.920692, "longitude": -79.373646],
            ["title": "Sudbury, ON",     "latitude": 46.488938, "longitude": -80.989838],
            ["title": "Saut Ste Marie, ON",     "latitude": 46.519658, "longitude": -84.348221],
            ["title": "Wawa, ON",     "latitude": 47.960502, "longitude": -84.858398],
            ["title": "Terrace Bay, ON",     "latitude": 48.806863, "longitude": -87.231445],
            ["title": "Thunder Bay, ON",     "latitude": 48.381338, "longitude": -89.301682]
        ]


        func calculateSegmentDirections(index: Int) {
            // 1
            let request: MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

            let start = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[index]["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: locations[index]["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
            let end = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[index+1]["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: locations[index+1]["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)

            let startPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: start, addressDictionary: nil)
            let endPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: end, addressDictionary: nil)

            let startMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: startPlacemark)
            let endMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: endPlacemark)

            request.source = startMapItem
            request.destination = endMapItem
            // 2
            request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
            // 3
            request.transportType = .automobile
            // 4
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
            directions.calculate {(response, error) -> Void in
                guard let response = response else {
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                    return
                }

                let route = response.routes[0]
                self.mapView.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)

                let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
                self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)

            }

        }

        for (index,location) in locations.enumerated() {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            if index+2 < locations.count {
                calculateSegmentDirections(index: index)
            }

        }
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        renderer.lineWidth = 4.0

        return renderer
    }
```

Comment: Please show some code and explain what you have tried already and why that doesn't work. In it's current state this question is too broad and is likely to be closed.

Comment: I don't believe there's any system function for this, you'd simply need to walk through your points adding up the distance between points until you reach or exceed the target distance.  If you exactly reach it, the location is the last point and you're done.  

Otherwise, calculate the fraction of the distance between the last pair of points that you need to get to the target and prorate the distance along that line segment by adding the differences in latitude and longitude between the points multiplied by the fraction you calculated to the second last coordinate point.